# Which software should be installed in Ubuntu Studio to work with video game music and sounds?

Tags: daw, sound-design

I make music and sounds for video games. 
Which software should I install on Ubuntu Studio for this purpose?

Comment: Which software/OS are you currently using?

Comment: Windows. I use to work FL Studio, Reason, SoundForge, Cubase and Famitracker.

Comment: call me confused, but ubuntu studio is a linux distro

Comment: This question is really open ended, probably [too open-ended](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). If you're just looking for DAW software there's [this question](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/679/easy-to-use-open-source-daw). If you have a specific need though, do edit your question so we can get you some good answers.

Comment: Sorry @FriendOfGeorge and Warrior Bob for being confused. I  currently use Windows but i've installed Ubuntu Studio and trying to figure it out which programs (Daws, Sound Editors or you tell me) are the "must be installed" to make music and sounds for videogames.

Comment: As per @WarriorBob's comment - the question as it stands isn't really answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Ardour is the go-to DAW for Linux. As for software with more specific purposes, I would just search through the software center for whatever you're looking for and see which one you like best- maybe starting with the ones with higher ratings.

It is easier, with Linux, to take a more modular approach to music and sound development by using jack.